# Reusing text in RST for Sphinx Documentation

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm writing documentation in RST format and generating HTML using Sphinx.

I want to be able to write a paragraph in an RST file and reuse the same paragraph in a different RST file in the same folder. I want the reuse such that if I make a change in the original paragraph it should automatically change in all other files it has been referenced when i generate the HTML using Sphinx.

Is there any RST syntax to make this happen? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [include directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include).

For a basic include, reference the paragraph you want to reuse as follows:

```
Some text

.. include:: /path/to/file_to_include.rst

More text
```

In our example, the content of `file_to_include.rst` is `Included text`.
Sphinx will generate:

```
Some text

Included text

More text
```

As you can see in the docutils documentation (linked above), you can optionally specify a set of options, for example to restrict the included text to a range of lines.

Comment: Thanks! I am able to add in the complete text and also add in either start-line or end-line. But when I add in both start-line and end-line as parameters to display a range, it doesn't show up. Here is the syntax i'm using: .. include:: includedtext.rst
    :start-line: 11
  :end-line: 14

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you link to an example project with which I can reproduce the issue and provide your Sphinx/Docutils version?
Are you sure you are specifying the line numbers correctly? The line count starts at 0. The 'end-line' won't be included.